# to display number in exponential form after certain limit also limit number of digit after decimal

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a conversion tool for different units where i want to display number in exponential form if they exceed 1000(for eg if I/O 10001 then O/P 1.000E+04, if I/O 1000.1 then O/P 1.000E+03).Also for numbers less than 1 (if I/O 0.001 then O/P 1.000E-03, if I/O 9.84203533290685E-04 then O/P 9.842E-04.

Sorry if the qusetion is very simple but I am new to VB .net and pretty bad with maths.

Comment: sorry for not doing that.I'll do it very soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `String.Format`:

```
Dim numberToDisplay As Decimal = 12345.00M
Dim formattedNumber As String = String.Format("{0:E3}", numberToDisplay)
'or:
Dim formattedNumber As String = numberToDisplay.ToString("E3")
```

Then you can use `formattedNumber` to display where you like.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#EFormatString

Comment: Nice job, beat me by eight seconds!  +1

Comment: Yeah I literally just edited it to add the .ToString() as well as an extra cos it was specified that way in the article I linked.

Answer (score 1):

You typically just use the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) method and pass the desired formatting string to yield your desired result.

Format strings are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx